# Verify Error while trying to establish a connection to Websphere queue from a JBoss Server

Tags: jms, websphere, jboss5.x, ibm-mq

While trying to intialize the ConnectionFactory from a jobScheduler (running in jboss-5), to websphere queue, I get the below exception

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:67)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:633)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:592)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:591)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:568)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:135)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:131)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:455)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:267)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:166)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:276)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1138)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:862)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:502)
        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:447)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.parseIiopUrl(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1781)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.parseBootstrapURL(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1525)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:389)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:428)
        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:144)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
        at com.test.testBatch.jms.JMSUtil.initialize(JMSUtil.java:57)
        at com.test.testBatch.jms.JMSUtil.send(JMSUtil.java:90)
        at com.test.testBatch.job.OutboundChangesPollingJob.execute(OutboundChangesPollingJob.java:76)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:195)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,775 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0) Exception in thread "DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0"
2012-03-29 09:47:11,776 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/rmi/corba/NamedValueImpl
2012-03-29 09:47:11,777 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.parseIiopUrl(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1781)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,777 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.parseBootstrapURL(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1525)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,777 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:389)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,777 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:113)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,777 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:428)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,777 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:144)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,778 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,778 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at com.test.testBatch.jms.JMSUtil.initialize(JMSUtil.java:57)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,778 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at com.test.testBatch.jms.JMSUtil.send(JMSUtil.java:90)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,778 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at com.test.testBatch.job.OutboundChangesPollingJob.execute(OutboundChangesPollingJob.java:76)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,778 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:195)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,778 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,779 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unexpected error during load of: com.ibm.rmi.corba.NamedValueImpl, msg=Cannot inherit from final class
2012-03-29 09:47:11,779 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:181)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,779 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:276)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,779 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1138)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,779 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:862)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,779 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:502)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,779 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:447)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,779 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,780 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        ... 12 more
2012-03-29 09:47:11,780 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0) Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
2012-03-29 09:47:11,780 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,780 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,780 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,780 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:67)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,780 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:633)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,780 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:592)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,780 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,781 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:591)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,781 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:568)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,781 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:135)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,781 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:131)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,781 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:455)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,781 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:267)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,781 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:166)
2012-03-29 09:47:11,781 ERROR [STDERR] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-0)        ... 18 more
```

Since it is throwing classNotFound, i went and checked the lib folder and the class is present in the jar named "ibmorb.jar". (Not sure why ClassNotFound is thrown)

This is the naming factory which is getting initliazed in the IntialContext

```
com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory
```

Please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with which I resolved this is

- Deleted the IBM jars, if it is placed twice in the application
- If the same jars are placed separately in two applications (running in the
  same server), then, placed the jar files in jboss's lib folder (to
  avoid redundant)
- Placed jacorb.jar in jboss's lib folder, in order to avoid the usage 
  of java's default corba package

I followed these three steps and I didn't get this error !!!

Thanks for all your answers and efforts !! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The jar and context factory mentioned would tend to indicate that the WMQ client was borrowed from a WebSphere Application Server install rather than using the stand-alone WMQ client installer.  If that is the case you can likely fix this quite easily by installing the stand-alone client.  You can obtain this free (with registration) as a SupportPac.  These are by version so you have your choice of:

- V7.1 client is [SupportPacMQC71](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC71) (Preferred)
- V7.0 client is [SupportPacMQC7](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC7)
- V6.0 client is [SupportPacMQC6](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC6) (Out of support as of September 2012)

Note that installing the client from the IBM-supplied installer provides a number of additional features such as diagnostics for tracing, version display, initial verification test code, sample source code, etc.  This is the method of install that IBM will support so even though you can get it to work by copying the jars from the WMQ server install, using IBM's media is recommended.

Note also that the packaging of the Java and JMS classes has changed between versions.  It is important to know which version that you are using and refer to the corresponding docs for `CLASSPATH` and other config options.  The v7.1 implementation has many functional improvements and is the only version that will take advantage of the features on a v7.1 QMgr.  However it will connect to *any* version QMgr so if this is new development, try to use the v7.1 client now so that you don't end up needing to upgrade down the road.

The Infocenter links for each version of the client are:

- V7.1 Infocenter [Environment Varariables for JMS](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/jm10330_.htm) & [Installing classes for JMS](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/jm10300_.htm)
- V7.0 Infocenter [Clients](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaf.doc/cs10120_.htm) and [Using Java](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/uj10120_.htm) manuals
- V7.0 Infocenter [Clients](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaf.doc/cs10120_.htm) and [Using Java](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/uj10120_.htm) manuals

One of the utilities supplied with the IBM installer is the `setmqjmsenv` script (and `setmqjmsenv64` when installing the 64-bit client) in the `java/bin` directory.  You can look here to determine the `CLASSPATH` and other environment variables needed for your version of WMQ Client Classes for Java.